# Array size is declared, but still get error: index is out of range

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two lists (same length) with approximately 10 integers stored.
I run these through a for-loop to check them simultaneously against an `if` statement. I know that this list contains 1 value that answers true to the `if`-statement.
Indeed, my first Debug shows the right value (corresponding to the place of the value in the list, namely 8).

My second debug shows the corresponding value of this place, namely 71.
However, I get the following error when I try to give the value of the list (which is 71) to the first spot of the array `DefMarkerX[count]`.

> `IndexOutOfRangeException`: Array index is out of range.

I really don't know what the problem is, because I have declared the size of the array in an earlier stage.

My code is:

```
public static int Markers = 1;
public static int[] DefMarkerX = new int[Markers];
public static int[] DefMarkerY = new int[Markers];

// ....................................................

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < MarkerPosX.Count; i++)
{
   if (MarkerPosX[i] > 10 && MarkerPosX[i] < 246 && MarkerPosY[i] > 10 && MarkerPosY[i] < 246)
   {
        Debug.Log("i: " + i)
        Debug.Log("markerposx: " + MarkerPosX[i]);
        DefMarkerX[count] = MarkerPosX[i];
```

This last line shown is where I get my error.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you are setting the size of your array to 1 which means that if i > 0 it will be out of range. P.S., don't forget that arrays are 0 based so the first item in the array will be on position 0.

Comment: `count` remains 0 so it wouldn't throw any exception at all. Please post entire code.

Comment: You're defining `DefMarkerX` but then enumerating over `MarkerPosX` - which is it?

Comment: I've changed the array (DefMarkerX) into a List, which did the job for me. You guys are right, sorry for not showing more code. I make sure to be more comprehensive next time. Thanks for all your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant to do, but if you can't know the size of `DefMarkerX` beforehand, you could use a `List<int>`

```
public static List<int> DefMarkerX = new List<int>;

for (int i = 0; i < MarkerPosX.Count; i++)
{
   if (MarkerPosX[i] > 10 && MarkerPosX[i] < 246 && MarkerPosY[i] > 10 && MarkerPosY[i] < 246)
   {
       DefMarkerX.Add(MarkerPosX[i]);
   }
}
```

If you want to keep the index of `MarkerPosX` you can use a `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> DefMarkerX = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>;

for (int i = 0; i < MarkerPosX.Count; i++)
{
   if (MarkerPosX[i] > 10 && MarkerPosX[i] < 246 && MarkerPosY[i] > 10 && MarkerPosY[i] < 246)
   {
       DefMarkerX.Add(new KeyValuePair(i, MarkerPosX[i]));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed the array to a List and it works fine now. I thought an array would be sufficient as well, because I did know the size of the array (which was equal to Markers).

Comment: If it has been useful please consider to accept it.